# How can I print all unicode characters?

Tags: python

I want to print some unicode characters but `u'\u1000'` up to `u'\u1099'`. This doesn't work:

```
for i in range(1000,1100):
    s=unicode('u'+str(i))
    print i,s
```

Comment: Three of the answers here are functionally identical, posted within minutes of each other.

Also, while I know this asks for unicode in a certain range, in case anyone came here looking to print the full range, this functionally identical answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33043329/1397555) (and a duplicate question too) gives that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [unichr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unichr):

```
s = unichr(i)
```

From the documentation:

> `unichr(i)`
>
> Return the Unicode string of one character whose Unicode code is the integer i. For example, unichr(97) returns the string u'a'.

Answer (score 18):

You'll want to use the [unichr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unichr) builtin function:

```
for i in range(1000,1100):
    print i, unichr(i)
```

Note that in Python 3, just [chr()](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#chr) will suffice.

Answer (score 7):

Try the following:

```
for i in range(1000, 1100):
    print i, unichr(i)
```

Comment: Just for fun, here is how awful it is to try and do this without `unichr()`: `print i, eval(r"u'\u" + hex(i)[2:].rjust(4, '0') + "'")`

Comment: @FJ: `eval(r"u'\u%04x'" % i)`

Comment: Using string substitution and eval is not a good recommendation for a beginner.  Pointing the OP to a built-in function specifically designed for this purpose was the correct and ideal answer.

Answer (score 6):

[`unichr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unichr) is the function you are looking for - it takes a number and returns the Unicode character for that point.

```
for i in range(1000, 1100):
    print i, unichr(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

(Python 3) The following will give you the characters corresponding to an arbitrary unicode range

```
start_code, stop_code = '4E00', '9FFF'  # (CJK Unified Ideographs)
start_idx, stop_idx = [int(code, 16) for code in (start_code, stop_code)]  # from hexadecimal to unicode code point
characters = []
for unicode_idx in range(start_idx, stop_idx+1):
    characters.append(chr(unicode_idx))
```

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this rather old post and played a bit ...

Here you find the Unicode blocks:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block

And here I am printing some of the blocks

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

ranges = list()

# Just some example ranges ... 
# Plane 0 0000–ffff - Basic Multilingual Plane
ranges.append((0x0000, 0x001f, 'ASCII (Controls)'))
ranges.append((0x0020, 0x007f, 'ASCII'))
ranges.append((0x0100, 0x017f, 'Latin Extended-A'))
ranges.append((0x0180, 0x024f, 'Latin Extended-B'))
ranges.append((0x0250, 0x02af, 'IPA Extensions'))
ranges.append((0x0370, 0x03FF, 'Greek'))
ranges.append((0x4e00, 0x9fff, 'CJK Unified Ideographs')) 

# Plane 1 10000–1ffff - Supplementary Multilingual Plane
ranges.append((0x1f600, 0x1f64f, 'Emoticons'))
ranges.append((0x17000, 0x187ff, 'Tangut'))

for r in ranges:
    # print the header of each range
    print(f'{r[0]:x} - {r[1]:x} {r[2]}')
    j = 1
    for i in range(r[0], r[1]):
        if j % 80 == 0:
            print('')
        j += 1

        print(f'{str(chr(i))}', end='')
    print('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `chr` instead of `unichr` to avoid an error message.

```
for i in range(1000, 1100):
    print i, chr(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see an answer with usage of str.isprintable() above.
Also there is no formal answer to the subject "How can I print **all** unicode characters", so I would give a try...

First - some unicode characters are non-printable. Therefore you can't print all them "as is". You can just print some representation of corresponding character. Here is a small code how to print all printable unicode characters, while for non-printable ones - their "\u...." representation will be printed:

```
for i in range(0x0000, 1 + 0xffff, 1):
    if str.isprintable(chr(i)):
        print(chr(i))
    else:
        print("Non-printable character: '\\u" + format(i, '04x') + "'")
```

Note: You can remove the prefix *Non-printable character:* above if don't need it. The code was tested with Python 3.8.7 .

Second - the term "printable" depends on your output device (e.g. console-output supporting utf-8 symbols, or console-output supporting only ASCII symbols, or console supporting only characters in certain code-page-encoding, etc.). Correspondingly you might need additionally to encode & decode your characters to be "supported" by the output device, or - if applicable - change the current encoding of the output device itself (e.g. see the *sys.stdout.encoding* , *codecs.getwriter*, *PYTHONIOENCODING*, etc.). But this would be a different topic.

Comment: str.isprintable() will work the range U+1000..U+1100 in the question but it isn't a generic solution, python's definition of a printable character is vastly different to Unicode's definition.

Comment: @Andj: the subject of original question was "How can I print **all** unicode characters?" So it's not about limited range of characters, but about all characters. In the topic-description was given example  range, where original approach doesn't work.
Unicode standard (e.g. https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode15.0.0/UnicodeStandard-15.0.pdf ) has no definition of term "printable" exists. Even more - when it was asked about count of "printable" characters - the (re-phrased) answer was "it depends". Please see details here:
https://www.unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2002-m04/0298.html

Comment: @Andj: python definition for "printable" being "mapped" with terms of unicode specification:
str.isprintable()
_Return True if all characters in the string are printable or the string is empty, False otherwise. Nonprintable characters are those characters defined in the Unicode character database as “Other” or “Separator”, excepting the ASCII space (0x20) which is considered printable. (Note that printable characters in this context are those which should not be escaped when repr() is invoked on a string. It has no bearing on the handling of strings written to sys.stdout or sys.stderr.)_

Comment: @dr-ckyhc, you need to be a bit more skeptical of Python documentation, regarding Unicode support. There are lots of divergences. Using str.isprintable() over all characters from U+0000 to U+10FFFF, the count for printable characters is 144516. If I use the Unicode set [:print:] (in Posix notation, or [[\p{graph}][\p{blank}] - [\p{cntrl}]] in Perl notation, The sets contain 287279 characters. A substantial difference in interpreting what is a printable character. Note that both figures are for the same version of Unicode.

Comment: Also that email you linked to, was discussing the property Default_Ignorable_Code_Point, where the Unicode set matches 4174 codepoints, and isn't necessarily part of the definition of printable characters. It was also referring to Unicode version 3.2.0, a lot of additional properties and derived properties now exist that didn't back then. And the definition I use was first introduced in 3.2 but updated in version 4. So things were in a state of flux up ot version 4, and that would be reflected in comments relating to 3.2. Printable is a nebulous concept, Python's definition differs to UTS18.

Comment: A good example of Python vs Unicode differences is the default word tokeniser used in scikit-learn which is based around Python's `\b` and `\w` definitions which differ dramatically from the corresponding Unicode definitions, which plays havoc with many writing systems.

Comment: The print property of a character, is a binary property defined for regular expressions, and its definition is in UTS18. For Unicode definitions, it is insufficient to refer only to the Standard itself, many aspects are defined in the UCD and various additional reports and annexes.

Answer (score -2):

One might appreciate this **php-cli** version:

It is using html entities and UTF8 decoding.

Recent version of XTERM and others terminals supports unicode chars pretty nicely :)

```
php -r 'for ($x = 0; $x < 255000; $x++) {echo html_entity_decode("&#".$x.";",ENT_NOQUOTES,"UTF-8");}'
```